# Executing code inside a <script> tag with an external source

Tags: javascript

Why does this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("1111");
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js">
</script>
```

result in "1111" being alerted, but this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js">

alert("111");
</script>
```

doesn't cause "111" to alert? Is it not possible to put code in the same `<script>` tag that loads an external script?

Comment: DOES NOT COMPUTE

Comment: It isn't clear from your question the nature of the problem in a way that we can help.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - Yes, but your fix for the markup isn't written properly in actual code blocks. So it's still hard to differentiate between the markup and the broken English. I have fixed the markup correctly.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: Someone who can edit posts should know that code has to be indented by four spaces... don't use HTML entities!!

Comment: @Felix - Or simply select the code and click the code block button and it does it for you.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, the funny thing is, you did the hardest possible method for creating a code block, for any moment.

Comment: @Fyodor - Because your method requires the most keystrokes of all. Don't confuse arrogance with wisdom sir.

Comment: @Fyodor - Which achieved an incorrect fix.

Comment: @Fyodor, sure I guess it's not the hardest. but it's still the last thing I would do.

Comment: @fyodor - your way sucks

Answer (score 7):

Well, this is just how the `<script>` tag works. If you have a `src` attribute, the content of the tag gets ignored.

Simply use another `<script>` tag, what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

The below JavaScript is correct:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <script type="text/javascript"> alert("1111"); </script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js"> </script>
     </head> 
     <body>
          <p> The actual script is in an external script file called "xxx.js".</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

If you only want one script tag then put the

```
 alert("1111");
```

inside of the xxx.js file.

The alert doesn't work when it is placed in between the script tag with a src because that is the way it is intended to work. It ignores anything between the open and closing script tags when src is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is attempting to reference a script from an external file called xxx.js in this case located in the same folder as the html file.  If you created that file and placed the alert into that file and moved your script block into the head tag then you would find it would work.

Placing javascript in external files is an encouraged practice because it allows you to reuse common functions in many pages with a simple inlcude statement in your html.  Plus it keeps your html files much cleaner.

When you start writing lots of javascript you can combine all your script into one file and then minify it using something like JSMin : http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

This compresses all your script into a tiny form that is unreadable to humans but is much quicker for your sites visitors because it means the script file is smaller and there is only one request to serve the file to the client.

On a side note, another helpful tool when writing javascript is [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

It parses your javascript and informs you of syntax errors and also bad practices.

Happy Coding

Paul